# Assigning many variables in a single code line C#

Tags: c#, pointers, assignment-operator, assign

I'm not sure of what the operation is called that I want to do in C#, but I know it can be done in other languages.

Suppose I have three vars and set them to the same value:

```
MyObject Ob1 = new MyObject(ID:1); 
MyObject Ob2 = Ob1;
MyObject Ob3 = Ob1;
```

(suppose those vars are NOT in the same context and I just cannot substitute them for a single one, nor can I know if they even exist. They can be one, two, or hundreds representing the same object...)

I know changes I make to the object through the `Ob3` will actually change the objects in `Ob1` and `Ob2` (of course, they all represent the same object with ID:1).

But if I assign something to `Ob3`, using `Ob3 = new MyObject(ID:2)`, this will not change the values of `Ob1` and `Ob2`, for they will continue to represent the object with ID:1.

```
// What happens:
Ob3 = new MyObject(ID:2);
// Ob3 is no longer the same as Ob1 and Ob2, wich are still the ID:1 object.
```

What I want to do is to assign all three variables at once, like when I write some correspondant code to `Ob3 = new  MyObject(ID:2);`, all other vars comes to represent the object with ID:2, not the ID:1 anymore.

```
//What I want:
Ob3 = new MyObject(ID:2); //using the suited operators I don't know
//And Ob1 and Ob2 become the ID:2 object as well.
```

I know it's possible to be done using pointers in C++ (obviously with a few changes in declarations and assignments), but I don't want to be managing things in an unmanaged language. So is there a similar way to do that "backward" assigning in C#??

Comment: if you're going to be treating all the same, everywhere, what's the point of having 3 of them? just use Ob1 in all places Ob2 and Ob3 are used and you'll have achieved what you're asking for

Comment: ^ This. I see where you're coming from but a variable is just a reference to a location, when you change a property off the reference, you're changing the same location. When you change the actual location by changing the variable itself, it obviously changes where it's pointing.

Comment: Stan, those vars are not in the same context.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that.  You've basically got three 'tokens' (Ob1, Ob2, and Ob3) that just happen to point to the same MtObject in memory.  If you assign a new MyObject to one of those tokens, then that token is pointing to that new MyObject in memory.  I'm curious as to why you want to intentionally have three separate tokens point to the same thing.  Would all you really want to do is say "Ob1.ID = 2"?  Since Ob1, Ob2, and Ob3 all point to the same thing, then that MyObject in memory will get it's ID changed, thus the three will reflect that.

Comment: I have an indefinite number of objects containing indefinite number of SubObjects as members. And I have indefinite number of ReferencerObjects that should store indefinite number of those SubObjects. I want to recreate one of those SubObjects and automatically replicate that change in all ReferencerObjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
MyObject Ob1 = new MyObject(ID:1), Ob2 = Ob1, Ob3 = Ob1;
```

and all 3 will point to the same object.  But, if you then say

```
Ob3 = new MyObject(ID:2);
```

Ob1 and Ob2 will still point to the same MyObject, and Ob3 will point to a new MyObject.  Thats because they're reference types, so the value stored in Ob1 is basically a pointer to the object itself.  What you want is for all 3 things to point to the same thing.  If MyObject is updatable, you could say something like

```
Ob3.Reset(ID:2);
```

if not, you could try this, but it is pretty silly.  This will let you do what you're trying to do, but it would probably be better to think about whether what you're doing is really what you want to do.

```
Tuple<MyObject> Ob1 = new Tuple<MyObject>(new MyObject(ID:1)), Ob2 = Ob1, Ob3 = Ob1;
Ob3.Item1 = new MyObject(ID:2);
```

Edit: I'd like to qualify that I don't think that this will generally be a good thing to do, it is a bit of a hack.  There may be a few cases where its useful, but holding your variables inside of tuples isn't something to do generally.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyObject obj1  //This create a reference variable on the stack
obj1 = new MyObject(ID:1)  //This create a new object of type MyOjbect on the heap and then assigns the memory location of this new object to obj1.

MyObject obj2 //This creates a reference variable on the stack, pointing at nothing
obj2 = obj1   //This assigns the memory location of the object (already created) on the heap to the reference variable on the stack
```

Same thing for obj3.

What you want to do the way you want to do it is impossible, you need to explicitely tell the reference variables obj1 and obj2 to point to the object created here:

```
Ob3 = new MyObject(ID:2);
```

Because obj1 is NOT an object, obj2 is NOT an object, obj3 is NOT an object. Its a reference to the memory location of an object. So if you tell obj3 to create a new instance (create a new object of type MyObject) on the heap, that has absolutey nothing to do with where obj1 or obj2 point to

Here is a picture to help in understanding

[image]

**Reference variables hold a HEX number of the memory location where the object lives on the heap. So when you assign one reference variable to another, you are actually just copying a hex number from one to the other, and this hex number represents WHERE the object lives**

Comment: @Daniel elaborate. Reference variables are the same idea as a pointer except its for objects only (kind of). In C++ you don't work directly with objects, you work with pointers that point at objects - very similar to references

Comment: In C++ I can use (*Pointer) = value; and thus, all pointers to that object will be pointing to that new value. (that's exactly what I want to do, but in C#, managed language);

Comment: `*Pointer` is c++ says "whatever I'm pointing to". If you cout `&Pointer` it will print out the hex memory location of where the object lives. You aren't working directly with objects

Comment: I see. I understand pointers, I was just wondering if there's some similar "whatever I'm pointing to" in C#.

Comment: @Daniel ahh, its automatic, you actually have to use another function to be able to pull out the hex number from a ref variable

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
MyObject Obj1, Obj2, Obj3 = new MyObject(ID:1);
Obj1 = Obj2 = Obj3 = new MyObject(ID:2);
```